# How to get dynamic count in datatable across all pages using serverside-angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-datatables

Trying to get dynamic count of the columns across all pages(selecting few records in first page, few records in another page). But if we changed to another page, first page selected records are deleted and showing only second page records.
Tried this below code for dynamic count.

```
const selectedPersons = this.persons.filter(f => f.checked).map(m => m.id);
    const totalAmount = selectedPersons.length
      ? selectedPersons.reduce((sum, current) => parseInt(sum) + parseInt(current))
      : 0;
    return totalAmount.toLocaleString();
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/serversidepagination-dynamic-count)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

First of all if you have not given unique id to the person then do it.

Change In Input tag:

```
<input [name]="person.id" (change)="checkedUnchecked($event, person)"  type="checkbox" [disabled]="person.firstName === 'Superman'" class="checkboxCls"  [(ngModel)]="person.checked">
```

Replace **get checkboxCheckCount()** with following:

Your count consist addition of **amount**(here **amount** is **person id** in your explaination, i have done same for you, but in future you can replace with **amount**)

```
allSelectedPersons = [];
  checkboxCheckCount = 0;

  checkedUnchecked(event, person) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.allSelectedPersons.push(person);
      this.checkboxCheckCount += parseInt(person.id);
    } else {
      this.allSelectedPersons = this.allSelectedPersons.filter(
        f => (f.id = !person.id)
      );
      this.checkboxCheckCount -= parseInt(person.id);
    }
  }
```

Change in AJAX:

```
  ajax: (dataTablesParameters: any, callback) => {
    dataTablesParameters.minNumber = dataTablesParameters.start + 1;
    dataTablesParameters.maxNumber =
      dataTablesParameters.start + dataTablesParameters.length;
    this.http
      .post<DataTablesResponse>(
        'https://angular-datatables-demo-server.herokuapp.com/',
        dataTablesParameters,
        {}
      )
      .subscribe(resp => {
        console.log(resp.data);
        this.persons = resp.data;
        this.persons.forEach(f => {
          f.checked = this.allSelectedPersons.find(
            person => person.id == f.id
          );
        });

        callback({
          recordsTotal: resp.recordsTotal,
          recordsFiltered: resp.recordsFiltered,
          data: []
        });
      });
  },
```